# How to make a deep copy of JAXB object like xmlbean XmlObject.copy()?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have been tasked with refactoring some components that used xmlbeans to now make use of jaxb. Everything is going great, until I get to a place where the previous author has called the [copy() function of one of the XmlObjects](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html#copy()). Since all objects in xmlbeans extend XmlObject, we get the magic deep copy function for free.

Jaxb does not seem to provide this for us. What is the correct and simple way to make a deep copy of a Jaxb object?

Comment: I'm curious to learn why you're moving from XMLBeans to JAXB, we use XMLBeans and have been considering comparing it to JIXB to see if we can get some performance benefits, what was your motivation for change?

Comment: Well, there are a few reasons, the primary reason being that xmlbeans enum support is a bit sketchy, the interface of the generated code is a bit odd and all objects extend XmlObject and we would prefer that the generated classes be completely independent of anything not included in standard java. All of that, and Jaxb is not included in the base jdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your JAXB classes serializable and then deep copying an object by serializing and deserializing it. The code might look something like:

```
Object obj = ...  // object to copy

ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
out.writeObject(obj);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
Object copy = in.readObject();
```

Comment: You don't really need to make them serializable, since the entire purpose behind JAXB is marshalling objects to and from XML. You could marshall and unmarhsall the object to make a copy, but that's probably far less efficient than writing your own clone() function.

Comment: +1 I think this is the right way - it jives with other suggestions I have seen. Thanks for the example code.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there is some [non-negligible overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10870833/521799) in this solution over using `Object.clone()` directly. If performance is important, this should be avoided...

Answer (score 7):

You can refer this

```
public static <T> T deepCopyJAXB(T object, Class<T> clazz) {
  try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    JAXBElement<T> contentObject = new JAXBElement<T>(new QName(clazz.getSimpleName()), clazz, object);
    JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jaxbContext, contentObject);
    return jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(source, clazz).getValue();
  } catch (JAXBException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

public static <T> T deepCopyJAXB(T object) {
  if(object==null) throw new RuntimeException("Can't guess at class");
  return deepCopyJAXB(object, (Class<T>) object.getClass());
}
```

It works for me.

All the credit goes to https://gist.github.com/darrend/821410

Comment: This looks more clean.

Answer (score 4):

You can use JAXBSource

Say you want to deep copy a sourceObject, of type Foo.
Create 2 JAXBContexts for the same Type:

```
JAXBContext sourceJAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("Foo.class");
JAXBContext targetJAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("Foo.class");
```

and then do:

```
targetJAXBContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
  new JAXBSource(sourceJAXBContext,sourceObject);
```

Comment: I like this solution as it's using the JAXB framework, however the Context has to be created not as Foo.class but the JAXB generated schema namespace. You should point that out else the user will get an exception/runtime error from the framework failing to find the ObjectFactory. Also the example would greatly benefit from adding the actual code for getting the object (e.g. Foo target = targetJAXBContext.createUnmarshaller...)

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a base class for the generated jaxb objects using an annotation in the XSD...

```xml
<xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:appinfo>
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:superClass name="com.foo.types.support.JaxbBase" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
  </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
```

You can add the clonability support there using the xmlbeans base class as a template.

Comment: +1 I really like this idea - unfortunately, it does not fit into our use case (which is a little off the norm)