# How Do I Clone A JAXB Object

Tags: java, jaxb

I have some jaxb objects (instantiated from code generated from xsd by jaxb) that I need to clone. The Jaxb class does not appear to provide an interface for doing this easily. I can not hand edit the class and can not extend it - so I need to create a helper/utility method to do this. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the purpose of JAXB, I think the easiest way would be to marshall your object to XML and unmarshall it back.

Lots more discussions on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=jaxb+clone).

JAXB FAQ [suggests](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Working_with_generated_code_in_memory.html) [beanlib](http://beanlib.sourceforge.net/).

There's also some [discussion](http://www.nabble.com/cloning-JAXBElements-td4708089.html) (as well as a link to download) of a Cloneable plugin under jaxb2-commons, although I can't find any reference on the project page.

Comment: Yes - marshall-to-unmarshall worked perfectly. I am awarding you the answer. Of course - there is a time hit to this over serialization - but since it can't be serialized there are not  lot of other choices besides reflection.

Comment: Check out the following for a code example: http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-jaxb-to-implement-copy-operation.html

Comment: Marshalling / unmarshalling works quite nicely, but it is by far the slowest solution. You can be around 5x faster by using serialisation / deserialisation, or around 50x faster by using actual cloning. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10870833/521799)

Answer (score 4):

I've run benchmarks on various solutions for cloning a JAXB object. Here are some results:

1. Using [mofokom's xjc-clone plugin](http://www.mofokom.biz/artifactory/snapshots-public/mofokom/xjc-clone/) seems to be the fastest solution. It just lets all your generated artefacts implement [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and publicly overrides [`Object.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29). Unfortunately, this hasn't made it into Maven central (yet).
2. Generating [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) artefacts and serialising / deserialising them to a dummy stream is 10x slower than using Java's cloning mechanisms:

   ```
   public <T extends Serializable> T clone(T jaxbObject) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
     o.writeObject(jaxbObject);
     o.flush();

     ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
     ObjectInputStream i = new ObjectInputStream(in);
     return (T) i.readObject();
   }
   ```
3. Marshalling / Unmarshalling the JAXB objects is again 5x slower than serialising / deserialising them. This is what [ykaganovich's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930867/521799) solution suggests:

   ```
   public <T extends Serializable> T clone(T jaxbObject) {
     StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();
     JAXB.marshal(jaxbObject, xml);
     StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml.toString());
     return JAXB.unmarshal(reader, jaxbObject.getClass());
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use the xjc-clone plugin? I can't seem to find any documentation for this plugin? Do you have to use it along with eclipse?

Comment: @bot: As a matter of fact, I've found a better solution by now, involving Maven and the official `jaxb2-basics` plugin. A similar solution to the one I've found is documented [here](http://arnekroeger.blogspot.ch/2011/06/java-jaxb-extend-generated-classes.html). I'll update the answer when I have time

Comment: I managed to make the generated classes clonable using the xjc-clone plugin and ant. Is there a link describing a way to use jaxb2-basics plugin with ant?

Comment: @bot: I've only used Maven so far. Feel free to post your findings as an answer to this question here, though...

Answer (score 3):

You should try [cc-xjc](http://ccxjc.sf.net), which is available on sourceforge. One of its features is to generate clone() and copy-constructors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Copyable plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki#jaxb2-basics-plugins). It generates deep copy/clone methods (which can be even customized with strategies).

Comment: 1, probably ;-) Which is a lot for simple POJOs, which can probably just be cloned using [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29). Do you know why the dependency is added? I mean, what makes jvnet's cloning procedures more robust?

Comment: Well, this plugin does much more that that. You can "copy onto" another object, use strategies to customize copying (how exactly should this or that be copied), use locators to check what exactly is being copied at the moment and so on. But the main reason for dependency is to avoid generating the same cloning code all over the place for each of the fields of each of the generated classes. The copying algorithmic is held in copy strategies.

Answer (score 2):

We have used the jaxb2-basics plugin - it is available in Maven repo, adds only a single dependency and can also be used to generate other useful stuff: equals, hashCode, toString, default values etc.
Please see this link for details: http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/cloning-a-jaxb-object/

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but I had to create cloneable JAXB domain objects too and I think that marshalling - unmarshalling is not the best solution for sure.

Ideally you should copy the objects in memory using generated clone methods. There is a Maven plugin (**maven-jaxb2-plugin**) which you can use for this purpose.

These are the relevant section in my Maven pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xjb</bindingDirectory>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note the **-Xcopyable** argument which generates the clone method inside of all objects.

If you use

```
mvn clean install
```

for building the project this will generate the domain classes with a clone implementation.

This is an extract of the clone related methods in one of the domain classes:

```
public Object clone() {
    return copyTo(createNewInstance());
}

public Object copyTo(Object target) {
    final CopyStrategy2 strategy = JAXBCopyStrategy.INSTANCE;
    return copyTo(null, target, strategy);
}
```

You can find the sources and samples of the jaxb2 basics project on this page:

https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/Sample-Projects

The releases with useful examples can be downloaded from here:

https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/releases